# How should I write an Entity Framework migration that transforms data (preferably using the DbContext)?

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-migrations

Say my object has a Name field, and I wish to split it into FirstName and LastName fields. Or maybe it has an address string and I'm adding Lat and Lng fields that require geocoding. Etc etc.

I expected to have access to my DbContext in the Up() and Down() methods, but all I've been able to find (besides the builtin functions) is the .Sql() call. This is enough for adding and removing columns, but not for transforming existing data into new formats.

Is it safe to reference my DbContext inside an Up() invocation? Or is there another recommended pattern for implement migrations that require more than trivial SQL?

Answer (score 0):

No you cannot use `DbContext` inside `Up` method because it already refers new model but your database still targets the old model.

Edit:

All data migrations must be done through `Sql`. You can for example create temporary table, move old data to temporary table, use migration of table structure and move data from temporary table back to the original with using some transformation directly in SQL - splitting varchar values should not be a big deal.

Comment: My required transformations cannot be done as SQL (splitting varchars was a radically oversimplified example). This kind of migration operation is very natural in a duck-type ORM like ActiveRecord, but it makes sense that this is an area where the EF approach would have trouble.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than trying to split the Name into two different fields, rethink your migration. Sometimes it might be best staged. I can think of two ways to perform your transformation.

**Migration path #1: New Fields, then Delete old**

1. Create migration for new field for FirstName and LastName, and in the Up() method, you still have the Name field, split it, insert into First and Last fields.
2. Create another migration to remove the old Name field.

**Migration path #2: Repurpose and Rename**

1. Create a migration adding the LastName field, and renaming Name to FirstName, move the last name data, modify the renamed First/Name field to only hold the first name.

Both paths have advantages and disadvantages. And regardless of the complexity of your transformation, you should be able to break it out into logical stages to accomplish the goal.